# In which scenario would you want to have two adjacent pooling layers?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, convolution, pooling

In which scenario, when assembling a CNN, would you want to have two adjacent pooling layers, without a convolutional layer in between?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're not referring to any particular type of pooling operation, it's possible that you could have, for example, a mean pool followed by a max or min pool. What this could do is combine the idea of reducing the dimensionality of your data from a holistic perspective with the mean pool, and then choosing the best of your averages with your max pool.